# DlookUp Function in ACCESS Query

Tags: database, microsoft-access, sharepoint

I am working on 2 databases that are linked together: Action Items List and UserInfo. I have imported the Action item List from my Sharepoint site.

[image]

I am trying to display only the "actions" that match with the criteria [Enter your name]. In order to do so, I have looked at the relationship of the 2 databases and we can see that "Owner.Value" (text attribut of the "Action Items list" database) is connected to "ID" (the foreign key of UserInfo database). In order to get the expected results, I run the querry and I enter my name but I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

Maybe someone could help me. I rely on your expertise. Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: String literal in function parameter must be enclosed with quotes. `"Name='" & [Enter your name] & "'"`. And remember, that input value which contains quotes will break your query... Use function for parameter input, check and quote.

Comment: Hi @Akina, thank you for your comment. Can you be a bit more specific please? To enlighten you, I am trying to only display the actions that were owned by the person who input his name when the querry is triggered. I am also aware that the fact that the "Owner" field of the table Action Item list is a text type attribute points at the numerical foreign key "ID" of the table UserInfo and I feared that would cause me difficulties to call the function DLookUp(). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to correct your `DLookup` expression: since the criteria is filtering the value of a text field (`Name`), the value used for the filter must be enclosed within single or double-quotes, else the result will be:

```
Name = Thomas Orvain
```

With `Thomas` and `Orvain` treated as separate fields in the resulting SQL.

To remedy this, you could change the `DLookup` expression to:

```
DLookup("Name", "UserInfo", "Name = '" & [Enter your name] & "'")
```

---

However, since you have already constructed an `INNER JOIN` between the `Action Items List` table & `UserInfo` table, the `DLookup` expression is **not required at all**.

Instead, you can apply selection criteria to the `Name` field directly, e.g. copy the following to the SQL view of your query:

```sql
select 
    [Action Items List].Action,
    [Action Items List].Status,
    [Action Items List].Owner.Value
from
    [Action Items List] inner join UserInfo on
    [Action Items List].Owner.Value = UserInfo.ID
where
    UserInfo.Name = [Enter your name]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lee Mac I haven't practiced much SQL Querries on access since I just have been working on this tiny project for my internship. You enlighten me so much! Thanks a lot! Cheers,Thomas.